# Hangman game Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a hangman game using JavaScript.

I've come at impasse and can't find any answers online. I'm trying to create a function for when the letter is clicked, it checks to see if its in the word. And if it's in the word, it will replace the "_" with the letter. I've tried looking through other forums but I can't find anything.

Code:

```js
let category = document.querySelector('.category')
let word = document.querySelector('.word')
let lives = document.querySelector('.lives')
let clue = document.querySelector('.clue')
const hintbutton = document.querySelector('.hint')
const playAgainButton = document.querySelector('.play-again')
let userLives = 10
let guessed = []

// generate random word
const gameWords = ['Doctor', 'MichaelJackson', 'Prince', 'Giraffe', 'LionKing']
let result = gameWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameWords.length)]

console.log(result)


// create a _ for each letter that is in the word 
function randomWord() {
  let str = " ";
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    str = str + "_ "
  }
  return str
}
word.innerHTML = randomWord()

// Hint function. returns a clue when hint button is clicked 

function hint() {
  hintbutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (result == 'MichaelJackson' || result == 'Prince') {
      return clue.innerHTML = 'Clue - Music Artist'
    } else if (result == 'Giraffe') {
      return clue.innerHTML = 'Clue - Animal'
    } else if (result == 'Doctor') {
      return clue.innerHTML = 'Clue - Occupation'
    } else {
      return clue.innerHTML = 'Clue - Movie'
    }
  })
}

hint()



// once letter is clicked the letter is greyed out and can no longer be clicked 
function fadeOut() {
  const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letter')
  letters.forEach(letter => {
    letter.addEventListener('click', function() {
      letter.style.opacity = '0.4'
    })
  })
}


// when user clicks a letter: if letter is in word. letter appends to the place where letter is in the word.
// if letter is not in word the user loses a life
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Hangman Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">Hangman</div>
    <div>Use the alphabet below to guess the word, or click hint to get a clue</div>
    <div class="letters">
      <button class="letter">a</button>
      <button class="letter">b</button>
      <button class="letter">c</button>
      <button class="letter">e</button>
      <button class="letter">d</button>
      <button class="letter">f</button>
      <button class="letter">g</button>
      <button class="letter">h</button>
      <button class="letter">i</button>
      <button class="letter">j</button>
      <button class="letter">k</button>
      <button class="letter">l</button>
      <button class="letter">m</button>
      <button class="letter">n</button>
      <button class="letter">o</button>
      <button class="letter">p</button>
      <button class="letter">q</button>
      <button class="letter">r</button>
      <button class="letter">s</button>
      <button class="letter">t</button>
      <button class="letter">u</button>
      <button class="letter">v</button>
      <button class="letter">w</button>
      <button class="letter">x</button>
      <button class="letter">y</button>
      <button class="letter">z</button>
    </div>
    <div class="category">The chosen category is</div>
    <div class="word"> </div>
    <div class="lives">you have 10 lives! </div>
    <div class="clue">Clue - </div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="hint">Hint</button>
      <button class="play-again">Play again</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried creating an event listener for each button and writing an `if statement` once the button is clicked.

I'm not sure if that's the right way to approach it, but I'm not even sure how to start the code for matching the clicked letter with the word.

Comment: Please show the event listener you tried writing. We'll help you fix it, we won't do it for you.

Comment: You can use `if (result.includes(letterClicked))` to test if the chosen letter is in the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the element clicked using `this`. `this.innerHTML` will give the letter clicked.

You can check if the letter is in the word using `indexOf`, if it returns -1 then the letter is not in the word.

Letter buttons are lowercase but `result` contains a mixture of upper and lower cases. Suppose `result = 'Giraffe'`. If `g` is clicked, it will not match `G`. Therefore `toLowerCase` is used to make `result` lowercase so matching will succeed.

```
const category = document.querySelector('.category')
const word = document.querySelector('.word')
const lives = document.querySelector('.lives')
const clue = document.querySelector('.clue')
const hintbutton = document.querySelector('.hint')
const playAgainButton = document.querySelector('.play-again')
let userLives = 10
const guessed = []

// generate random word
const gameWords = ['Doctor', 'MichaelJackson', 'Prince', 'Giraffe', 'LionKing']
const result = gameWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameWords.length)]

console.log(result)


// create a _ for each letter that is in the word 
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    guessed.push('_')
}

word.innerHTML = guessed.join('')

hintbutton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (result == 'MichaelJackson' || result == 'Prince') {
        return clue.innerHTML = 'Clue - Music Artist'
    }
    else if (result == 'Giraffe') {
        return clue.innerHTML = 'Clue - Animal'
    }
    else if (result == 'Doctor') {
        return clue.innerHTML = 'Clue - Occupation'
    }
    else {
        return clue.innerHTML = 'Clue - Movie'
    }
})

function letterHandler(){
    const letter = this.innerHTML
    const lowerResult = result.toLowerCase()
    // check if the letter is in the result
    if(lowerResult.indexOf(letter) != -1){
        for(i = 0; i < lowerResult.length; i++){
            // if the guessed letter matches the result, reveal it
            if(lowerResult[i] == letter){
                guessed[i] = result[i]
            }
        }
        word.innerHTML = guessed.join('')
        if(guessed.join('') == result){
            alert('You win!')
        }
    } else{
        userLives -= 1
        if(userLives == 0){
            alert('You lose!')
        }
        lives.innerHTML = 'You have ' + userLives + ' lives!'
    }
    this.disabled = true
}


// once letter is clicked the letter is greyed out and can no longer be clicked 
const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letter')
letters.forEach(letter => {
    letter.addEventListener('click', letterHandler)
})
```

I've also replaced some `let` with `const` where appropriate and removed functions like `hint` and `randomWord` which weren't really necessary. Using `disabled` instead of `style.opacity` has the same visual effect but means the event listener won't fire on buttons which have already been clicked.

Comment: thank you so much this helped a bunch! I definitely need to look into "this"  as ive been having a hard time grasping its functionally. your explanation was so detailed and concise. thank you for explaining how each function would work and the result! hope you have a great day

Comment: Glad I could help, [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler) provide a good explanation of how `this` works in an event listener

Answer (score 0):

you can use `innerHTML` for this and takeout the listnner of the `fadeout()`.
With that you have to deal with how to show the correct letters, the `word.includes(letter)` should be enough

```
const letters = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
letters.forEach((letter) => {
  letter.addEventListener("click", function () {
    letter.style.opacity = "0.4";
    console.log(letter.innerHTML);
    word.innerHTML = `<div> ${input.value}</div>`;
  });
});
```